# Qlik Sense and SAS Integration

Tags: sas

I have two platforms and what I want to do is, when I am using Qlik Sense, I want to tell SAS to do the some regression analysis on the table that I loaded on Qlik Sense and show me the results in Qlik Sense. Is it possible interconneting these two software?

Note: SAS ODBC connector is available but I am not sure if installing this will allow me to use SAS scripts on Qlik Sense Editor. It seems this tool only allows me to see SAS table on Qlik View. I am not sure if it allows me to send commands to SAS like regression, decision tree etc..

Comment: I'm not sure if SAS and Qlik sense can work that way. However, I tried R & Qlik sense, it's ok that way, from Qlik, we can call R functions and get results to visualize it on Qlik sense.

Comment: I dont know much about Qlik (sorry), but there was a discussion about SAS&Qlik integration in my company, and it seemed to be a solution to create a web service (or stored process) in SAS which would calculate what you want, and you call this web service in Qlik to retrieve your data and visualize it.

Comment: you can try , first analyze on sas and write it on table (or  txt..) then schedule on qlik sense report to read data from that table (or txt..)